# (Vim regex) Following by anything except bracket character

Tags: regex, vim

Test string:

```
best.string_a = true;
best.string_b + bad.string_c;
best.string_d ();
best.string_e );
```

I want to catch string that after '.' and followed by anything except '('. My expression:

```
\.\@<=[_a-z]\+\(\s*[^(]\)\@=
```

I want :

```
string_a
string_b
string_c
string_e
```

But it doesn't work and result :

```
string_a
string_b
string_c
string_d
string_e
```

I am new to vim regex and i dont know why :(

Answer (score 2):

Make this `\.\@<=\<[_a-z]\+\>\(\s*(\)\@!`

This matches:

```
\.\@<=          Assure a dot is in front of the match followed by
\<[_a-z]\+\>    A word containing only lowercase or '_' chars
\(\s*(\)\@!     not followed by (any amount of spaces in front of a '(')
```

Answer (score 1):

this would work for your needs too:

```
\.\zs[_a-z]\+\>\ze\s*[^( ]
```